# Procedure or function 'insert_grp' expects parameter '@mdate', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

when am using save_click am getting above error,this is my code

```
protected void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(obj_grp.checkExist(txt_grpname.Text)) != 0)
            {
                aler("grp", "grp name already exists");
                SetFocus(txt_grpname);
            }
            else
            {

                obj_grp.grp_NAME = txt_grpname.Text.Trim();
                obj_grp.effective_DATE = Convert.ToDateTime( txt_edate.Text);
                obj_grp.M_DATE = Convert.ToDateTime(txt_mdate.Text);
                int val = obj_grp.add();
                if (val > 0)
                {
                    aler("grp", "grpname Registered sucessfully");

                }
                else
                {
                    aler("grp", "group Not Registered ");
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;

        }
    }
```

my stored procedure is

```
create procedure [dbo].[insert_grp](@grpid int,@grpname varchar(50),@edate datetime,@mdate datetime)
as insert into grp values(@grpname,@edate,@mdate)
```

here grpid is identity....

Comment: Where are you calling your SP `insert_grp` **in CODE** ?

Comment: I think you should show the code for *obj_grp.add();* function

Comment: am using ntier architecture and am calling in entity layer...thanks fro ur reply

Comment: code for obj_grp.add is     public int add()
        {
            int retValue = 0;

            object odjValue = objper.AddPersistence(obj_grp_reg);
            if (odjValue != null)
            {
                retValue = 1;
            }
            return retValue;
        }

Answer (score 0):

if @grpid is identity, then why you are reciving it in stored procedure.

```
 create procedure [dbo].[insert_grp](@grpid int,@grpname varchar(50),@edate       datetime,@mdate datetime)
 as insert into grp values(@grpname,@edate,@mdate)
```

you are passing three values to procedure, thats why it couldnt assign the value to fourth paramter which is mdate. so make your stored procedure like

```
 create procedure [dbo].[insert_grp](@grpname varchar(50),@edate datetime,@mdate datetime)
 as insert into grp values(@grpname,@edate,@mdate)
```

Comment: thank you for ur help, but still am getting the same problem even i changed the stored procedure

Comment: Are you sure the value of mdate is not null?